# Open link in iframe on a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi there I had a working solution for this and the brief has changed somewhat meaning I now need to find a work around.

Scenario is that I have a button that when clicked opens a specific url in an iframe. This was working great with the following code:

```
<a class="two_nights iframebutton_pink" href="buttonurl" target="bookingiframe" onclick="location.href='#booking'">Januar</a>

<script>
$("[target='bookingiframe']").on('click',function () {
  $("#ifr").attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
  scrollt();
});
</script>
```

Which was moving down to the iframe on the page and changing the source. This is the iframe:

```
`<a id="booking"><div class="frame_container"><iframe name="bookingiframe" src="generalurl" width="100%" height="8000" frameborder="0" scrolling="0"></iframe></div></a>`
```

The content of the iframe now needs to be on a page that is white listed so this solution doesn't work. What I need to happen is for the button to be clicked and then open a new page with the iframe on and change the url to that of the button.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a page with Iframe.

suppose the URL is **yoursite.com/iFrame.html**

What you need now is to send your booking URL to that new page. So we will use URL param to do that.

So your final URL would look like 
**yoursite.com/iFrame.html*?url=h#tp://www/bookingurl.com.....***

Now on the new page you need the below extra code to get the URL from parameter and load the iFrame.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

After Pasting this now you can use your code to populate the iFrame.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ifr").attr('src',getParameterByName(url));
});
</script>
```

The function `getParameterByName` reads the booking URl and load the Iframe.

So the final code will be

```
<a class="two_nights iframebutton_pink" href="yoursite.com/iFrame.html*?url=h#tp://www/bookingurl.com....." target="bookingiframe" target="_blank">January</a>
```

And the JS code above

Comment: Thanks for being so super quick with your answer. Will try it now and will report back.

Comment: Okay, it is going to the new page but not loading the target url in the iframe, is that maybe because the iframe already has a set source? Or I have probably done something wrong. :)

Comment: I can certainly give it a go, how would that work though with it being on two pages?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mischiefbec/5rs6pLdt/ I have added the scripts and html here